# AMD & Nvidia, 3-monitor system, 22.04.3, update loses one monitor

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, multiple-monitors, radeon

```
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
product: Oland [Radeon HD 8570 / R5 430 OEM / R7 240/340 / Radeon 520 OEM]
product: GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
```

2 monitors on the Nvidia (GT710), one on the Radeon

Always had some struggle getting this 2-GPU, 3-monitor set up going, but after moving to 22.04, life was good--suspend even worked pretty reliably (modulo maybe the monitor order getting scrambled). But then some update or another happened and suddenly my middle monitor (AMD) was left inactive after startup. In the past, tinkering without knowing what I was doing would eventually get me going, but no joy this time, so I'm desperate enough to ask for help.  Couple of clues:

If I unplug one of the monitors hooked to the Nvidia, suddenly the monitor hooked to the AMD/Radeon comes to life. So, I can have a *different* two monitors, just not 3. Presumably this eliminates many possible hardware problems.

If I resurrect an old xorg.conf file from past blind tinkering, I can get all three monitors!  Alas, this now comes with constant freezes, which can be unstuck by switching to a different workspace and back. Not a bearable solution.

Seems like some high level software has decided I only want to use two monitors, though it doesn't care which two? I'm lost.

```
Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-470 (proprietary, tested)
```

Here's the old xorg.conf that will get me three monitors along with regular screen freezes:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 390.157  (dvs-builder@U64-E08-27-1)  Wed Oct 12 09:14:08 UTC 2022

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:1@0:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "amdgpu"
    BusID          "PCI:5@0:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```